# How do I override IInspectable::GetRuntimeClassName() for a WinRT (ref) class

Tags: c++, windows-runtime

According to the WinRT specification, private classes should override [IInspectable::GetRuntimeClassName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br205823%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and return a different name (or NULL). But since `IInspectable` isn't a ref class (it's a struct), I can't inherit from it, or override the methods.

Define from MSDN:

```
HRESULT GetRuntimeClassName(
  [out]  HSTRING *className
);
```

So the question is, how do I override `IInspectable::GetRuntimeClassName()` for a WinRT (ref) class?

Sample attempt:

```
#include "Hstring.h"
#include "Inspectable.h"
#include <sal.h>

namespace PhoneVoIPApp
{
    namespace BackEnd
    {
        namespace CallController
        {
            public interface class IHelloWorld 
            {
                Platform::String^ SayHello();
            };

            private ref class HelloWorldImpl sealed :IHelloWorld
            {
            public:
                virtual Platform::String^ SayHello();

                virtual HRESULT GetRuntimeClassName(_Out_ HSTRING *className) override;
            };

            Platform::String^ HelloWorldImpl::SayHello()
            {
                return L"Hello World!";
            }

            HRESULT HelloWorldImpl::GetRuntimeClassName(_Out_ HSTRING *className)
            {
                *className = nullptr;

                return E_NOTIMPL;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a chat with the CLR team, who pointed me to the correct answer.

When using private classes, a secret undocumented attribute, `Platform::Metadata::RuntimeClassName` can be added to the code.

So the solution to the problem is:

```
#include "Hstring.h"
#include "Inspectable.h"
#include <sal.h>

namespace PhoneVoIPApp
{
    namespace BackEnd
    {
        namespace CallController
        {
            public interface class IHelloWorld 
            {
                Platform::String^ SayHello();
            };

            private ref class HelloWorldImpl sealed : [Platform::Metadata::RuntimeClassName]IHelloWorld
            {
            public:
                virtual Platform::String^ SayHello();
            };

            Platform::String^ HelloWorldImpl::SayHello()
            {
                return L"Hello World!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```